# C++ Windows 7; How can I make all CPU threads sleep for a certain amount of time?

Tags: c++, windows-7, cpu, sleep, cpu-cores

I would like to make ALL of the CPU threads sleep for a certain amount of time in order to lower the CPU load.

Should I open 1 thread for each CPU thread and use the sleep function or is there a controlled way to target all of the CPU threads?

Comment: Prefer to use event driven programming rather than sleeping or spin loops.  With event driven, the OS can wake up the task when the event occurs rather than your program or task polling for the event.

Comment: Why do you want to make all CPU threads sleep? (By the way, this will make your computer freeze until they stop sleeping)

Comment: Making a software thread sleep is not the same as making a CPU thread sleep. The operating system will just choose another software thread to run on that CPU thread while the first one sleeps.

Comment: This programm will be only there to lower the CPU usage. The events won't happen randomly and only when called. The sleep fuction is currently just an option for now that I am looking to replace with something that can target the CPU threads better.

Comment: I am aware that it will freeze the whole operating system for a certain amount of time, which I don't mind, since it will deload the CPU usage. Do you have an idea how I could target the CPU threads and make them sleep without taking in other work?

Comment: maybe you should try decreasing your CPU frequency. There are probably some tools that can force a lower frequency. It is more efficient than doing things at high frequency and then doing nothing.

Comment: Thats a good idea, will definitely look into this aswell.